# SwiftUI - Not changing views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a form that I want to change views from if a Bool is false:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                Toggle(isOn: $ClientAnswer) {
                    Text("Client answer")
                }
                
                if ClientAnswer {
                    Toggle(isOn: $submission.fieldOne ) {
                        Text("Field One")
                    }
                    Toggle(isOn: $submission.fieldTwo ) {
                        Text("Field Two")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    if self.ClientAnswer{
                        self.placeSubmission()
                    }
                    else {
                        ShowRS() //**change views here.**
                        print("test")
                    }
                }){
                    Text("Submit")
                }
            }.disabled(!submission.isValid)
        }
    }
}
```

The code is being executed as `print("test")` works, but it doesn't change view it just stays on the same view?

The view I am trying to switch to is:

```
struct ShowRS: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("testImage")
    }
}
```

Comment: Which view do you want to be replaced by `ShowRS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include `ShowRS` in your view hierarchy -- right now, it's just in your `Button`s action callback. There are multiple ways to achieve this, but here's one option:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var moveToShowRSView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                if true {
                    moveToShowRSView = true
                }
            }) {
                Text("Move")
            }.overlay(NavigationLink(destination: ShowRS(), isActive: $moveToShowRSView, label: {
                EmptyView()
            }))
        }
        
    }
}


struct ShowRS: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("testImage")
    }
}
```

I've simplified this down from your example since I didn't have all of your code with your models, etc, but it demonstrates the concept. In the `Button` action, you test a boolean (in this case, it'll always return `true`) and then set the `@State` variable `moveToShowRSView`.

If `moveToShowRSView` is true, there's an `overlay` on the `Button` that has a `NavigationLink` (which is invisible because of the `EmptyView`) which will only be active if `moveToShowRSView` is `true`

Comment: Thanks, one thing, the view seems to be displayed regardless of if the isActive is true or false?

Comment: What view are you referring to?

Comment: `ShowRS()` The view on the `overlay`

Comment: Hm - I'm running the code I provided and ShowRS() only appears once you click the button. Are you running my code or did you try to translate it into your app and you're seeing it there? If so, can you post your updated code?